# Overriding template not showing up

Tags: magento2, overrides, template-hints, overriding

I am trying to override template of `Magento_Review` module

I added new layout file under my module

> app/code/Custom/CustomReview/view/frontend/layout/review_product_list.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.product_additional_data">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custum_CustomReview::product/view/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and template file

> app/code/Custom/CustomReview/view/frontend/templates/product/view/list.phtml

```
<h1>Overriding</h1>
```

and ny module.xml file look like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_CustomReview" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Review"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

But my template is not getting override. I cleared cache but no luck. Can anyone help what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override `review_product_listajax.xml` in your module. And add below code only. It will work!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.product_additional_data">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_ModuleName::product/view/list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

Flush cache and check.

Comment: Yeah but still not work :( I made review_product_list.xml but no luck

Comment: Have you created your custom theme?

Comment: no!! custom module. I dnt want to override it in theme

Comment: Mate, check I have updated code.

Comment: Thanks @sarvesh :) But the $review variable is not aviable in overrided template do I need to do something more to make $review variable accessible in my template

Comment: sorry @Daniel_12 I didn't understand you are talking about which $review variable? What does it have exactly?

Comment: @SarveshAhuja this works but just wanted to know how to pass new css

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
        <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.product_additional_data">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custum_CustomReview::product/view/list.phtml</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

> **update :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
    <body>
        <block class="Write_Class_your_block" name="product.info.product_additional_data" template="Custum_CustomReview::product/view/list.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: nop I doesn't work for me

Comment: Then redefine the block, this will trigger 100%.

Comment: how to redefine ? can you please tel me

Comment: try again, as I wrote back. I updated the answer.

Comment: do I need to make block ?

Comment: No, the one in which you wanted to insert your template

Comment: <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
<body>
    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" template="Custom_CustomReview::product/view/list.phtml"/>
</body>
</page>

Comment: But still not overriding :(

Comment: Are you make bin/magento c:c?

Comment: yes i did clean the cache

Comment: Yes I have -...

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.additional">
            <arguments>
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custum_CustomReview::product/view/list.phtml</argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** nee to create a **new module** just to override a template. override it in your current theme instead.

To override the xml `review_product_list.xml` :

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themeName}/Magento_Review/layout/override/base/review_product_list.xml
```

To override the a template :

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themeName}/templates/product/view/list.phtml
```

Good luck.